# Hide DIV if Attachment does not exist

Tags: javascript, php, css

Hey need some help hiding this div if the attachment does not exist. I think it might be quite a simple solution, my PHP is pooooooor. Any suggestions please.

```
   <!--Include Attachments to Post-->
<div class="attachments">
    <?php $attachments = new Attachments( 'attachments' ); /* pass the instance name */ ?>
        <?php if( $attachments->exist() ) : ?>
            <h3><strong>Attachments</strong></h3>
            </br>
            <?php while( $attachments->get() ) : ?>
            <h5><strong>Name:</strong> <?php echo $attachments->field( 'title' ); ?></h5>
            <h5><strong>Size:</strong> <?php echo $attachments->filesize(); ?></h5>
            <h5><strong><a href="<?php echo $attachments->url(); ?>"target="_blank">Download File</a></strong></h5>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: And what is the result? Why not `if ($attachments->exist()) { ....  }` instead of this weird construct?

Comment: Also it will always exist since you just created it no?

Comment: @mplungjan this snippet adds an area to our post page and if there is an attachment pulls through them relevant info. When there is no file added in the post editor it shows a blank space on the front end. We want to try and hide the div if so. Can this be done with inline CSS, Java or can we hide it based on post meta?

Answer (score 0):

Phoned a friend, got a result. Just needed to move the div within the if statement.

```
   <!--Include Attachments to Post-->
    <?php $attachments = new Attachments( 'attachments' ); /* pass the instance name */ ?>
        <?php if( $attachments->exist() ) : ?>
           <div class="attachments">
            <h3><strong>Attachments</strong></h3>
            </br>
            <?php while( $attachments->get() ) : ?>
            <h5><strong>Name:</strong> <?php echo $attachments->field( 'title' ); ?></h5>
            <h5><strong>Size:</strong> <?php echo $attachments->filesize(); ?></h5>
            <h5><strong><a href="<?php echo $attachments->url(); ?>"target="_blank">Download File</a></strong></h5>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```